# What's polarization out of a uniformly charged ball?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, polarization, dielectric

Let a ball be charged with uniform charge density $\rho_0$.

From the book Zangwill Modern Electrodynamics Equation 6.6 
$$P(r)=0, r\notin V$$

However, The simple dielectric matter Equation 6.35 stated that

$$P=\epsilon_0 E$$ (with $\chi=1$ for simplicity).

(Another equation, i.e. Poisson's formula, $E_p=-(P\cdot \nabla)\xi$ would arise the similar conclusion with Eq 6.35 that $P\neq0$.)

Thus, according to Equation 6.6 the polarization outside sphere was to be $0$.
However, use Equation 6.35 the polarization would be $\frac{\rho_0}{3}\frac{R^3}{r^3}\vec{r}$.

What exactly was the polarization outside a uniformly charged ball?

Comment: Why do you think $\chi =1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dielectric susceptibility *outside* the ball is $\chi=0$ (if it's vacuum).

Comment: Just to check $-\nabla \cdot P =\rho_g$ only work for continuous media when working with Gauss theorem?

Comment: $\rho_g$ here is the bound charge density. This is zero in vacuum, and since $P=0$, then Gauss's  theorem is satisfied. Or are you asking a different question altogether? @ShoutOutAndCalculate

Comment: Oh, wait. Suppose one use a uniform charged ball of bounded charge $\rho_p$.(The same as the question) Then use divergence theorem, $\int_V \rho_p {}_(r) dV = \int-( \nabla\cdot P) dV =\int_A P dA $ lead to a non zero polarization outside sphere, instead of $0$. However, inside vacuum it was $P=0$. Thus it implied that divergence theorem only apply to continuous material.

Comment: @ShoutOutAndCalculate I suspect you are not understanding what bounded charge is. The overall sphere is neutral in terms of bounded charge.

Comment: (If you were talking about Jackson, sure it was drawn in the book. However, it's an approximation. The original form and derivation was different.) The overall bounded charge to be neutral had three conditions. i.e. Zangwill Equation 6.4,6.5,6.6. In the case of an equally charged ball, the second expression 6.5 $\sigma_p= P\hat{n}$ did not hold(In the sense that $P$ would not be well defined) and thus the neutrality (Eq 6.3) doesn't necessarily hold.